# gradle ide eclipse plugin import gradle project build model results in UnsatisfiedLinkError: net

Tags: eclipse, gradle, ibm-rad, gradle-eclipse

I am running Rational Application Developer v9.0 and am attempting to import a gradle project using the Gradle IDE eclipse plugin (v3.4.0).

My Gradle project (a nested multi project build) builds correctly in the command line, however when I attempt to import it and click `build model` the console blurts out this ugly stack trace:

```
Problems handling incoming cache access requests.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net (C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP_1\jdk\jre\bin\net.dll is not a valid Win32 application. )
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1197)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1161)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:527)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:79)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:229)
    at java.net.DatagramPacket.<clinit>(DatagramPacket.java:60)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.receive(FileLockCommunicator.java:59)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler$1.doRun(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:66)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler$1.run(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
```

I used to be able to import the project without problems, but I am now getting this error and don't know why.

Your help is much appreciated :).

***Update:*** the log files in the .metadata directory of the workspace show a more detailed log message, any ideas?

```
!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 4 0 2014-02-07 12:40:03.751
!MESSAGE An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.ensureModels(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getGradleModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getSkeletalGradleModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizardPageOne$11.doit(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'HierarchicalEclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-rc-1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.attachCallerThreadStackTrace(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider.buildModel(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: Could not receive a message from the daemon.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ModelBuilderBackedConsumerConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:50434'.
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.io.ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.Message$ExceptionReplacingObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.Message.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.DefaultMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.ensureModels(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getGradleModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getSkeletalGradleModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizardPageOne$11.doit(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'HierarchicalEclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-rc-1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.attachCallerThreadStackTrace(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider.buildModel(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: Could not receive a message from the daemon.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ModelBuilderBackedConsumerConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:50434'.
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.io.ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.Message$ExceptionReplacingObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.Message.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.DefaultMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been fighting the same RAD9/Gradle plugin battle as well and finally got a successful import or a simple Java project.

Can you try installing Sun/Oracle JDK 7 somewhere, make sure Gradle itself is configured to use it, then go into RAD Preferences/Gradle/Arguments and set the Java Home to Workspace JRE: - which points to your Sun/Oracle Java 7 JDK (not JRE)?

[image]

I've changed so many things to try to get this to work it may require more than this setting; however, this one was certainly the final setting which allowed it to work. Please post back your findings. If it doesn't work for you I can post additional info about my setup (JAVA_HOME, GRADLE_HOME, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a a popup message about Gradle stating ""An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host", and my Elipse log file had the same as above. This worked for me on multiple occasions; here's what I did.

1. Have JDK installed on your computer (ex: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71).
2. Add to Eclipse under Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs, using same path above (ex: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71).
    (Note: You don't need to check it as the current active one here, you just need it installed.) 
   - Click Apply.
3. Set the Gradle > Arguments > Workspace JRE to the JRE you just added (the jdk one). 
   - Click Apply and OK.
4. Re-kick off the Gradle build. One time I got the same error again right away, but then tried a few things (clean projects, double-checked JRE/Gradle configuration, etc), and the build kicked off and cleared up my errors.